# How to join #tor irc channel oftc?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

i'm a new user and i'd like to connect #tor channel on oftc or hexchat 
on oftc i get the message :   #tor Cannot join channel (+i)

on hexchat i gzr the message :   trazomtg a mis le mode +i sur trazomtg
* Impossible de rejoindre le canal #tor (Vous devez être invité)

what can i do?
regards

Answer (score 2):

Nothing, the channel is closed temporarily due to abuse.

Wait until the +i is lifted, normally within a few hours or a few days.